# H2 transactions always automatically commit why?

Tags: java, transactions, h2

My app is only java and maven (no other frameworks)

In pom.xml I have a dependency to H2 database:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I created a connection in this way, **You can see that I set autocommit to false.** and my H2 database is in memory.

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    public static Connection getConnectionManager() throws SQLException {

        Properties myProp = new Properties();
        myProp.put("user"    , "sa");
        myProp.put("password", "");
        myProp.put("autocommit", "false");

       return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", myProp);
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

}
```

I created sample table:

```
public class InitDatabaseManager {

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SQL =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ("
                + "ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                + "EMAIL VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (ID))";

        private static final String DROP_TABLE_USERS = "drop table if exists users;";

        public static void initStarterTable (Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(DROP_TABLE_USERS);
            stmt.executeUpdate(CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
        }
    }
```

My question is why in below code the record i inserted to H2 database although I disable autocommit?

```
 public static void insertUsers(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    System.out.println("[INSERT]");

    String sqlInsert1 = "INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('user@mail.com');";
    PreparedStatement psInsert = connection.prepareStatement(sqlInsert1);

    System.out.println(connection.getAutoCommit());

    psInsert.execute();
    psInsert.close();

}
```

Comment: Where do you disable autocommit? Your `PreparedStatement` handling is also a bit off. Call `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` to start a transaction.

Comment: Unrelated to problem: A major reason to use a `PreparedStatement` is to facilitate _parameters_ in a SQL statement (e.g. `ps = prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)"); ps.setString(1, "user@email.com");`).

Comment: I have a method above insertUsers() and to test I set autocommit to false on connection but the record i always visible as inserted. I excpected to manually commit.

Comment: try `return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;LOCK_MODE=0;", myProp);`

Answer (score 1):

When you execute an `INSERT` command it inserts the specified row into the table. This row is visible only for the transaction that performed this operation, and not visible to other transactions (if they use the default “read committed” isolation level). After implicit (due to auto-commit) or explicit manual commit the inserted row becomes visible for all transactions. If you rollback the transaction instead of commit, the row disappears.

Other data modification operations work in the same way. Uncommitted changes are visible only to the transaction that performed them, committed changes are visible for everyone.

There are different isolation levels for transactions, but the default storage engine of H2 doesn't support them yet in 1.4.199 (such support is included in 1.4.200).

Each JDBC connection has own session and this session has own transaction. I guess you use the same connection to read the inserted data, therefore it can see uncommitted rows. Use another connection if you don't want to see them.

Data definition commands in H2 (such as `CREATE TABLE`) usually cause implicit commit, see the documentation of H2 for details.

Comment: Thx but are you sure that the default storage engine of H2 doesn't support diffrent isolation transaction level?

Comment: I'm sure. `Connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED)`, however, has some effect, but you shouldn't use **if you have more than one session**, it isn't the real “read uncommitted”. It only disables some locks and it may cause problems; the uncommitted data from other transactions may stay invisible. The legacy PageStore engine supports more levels, but it uses table-level locks, write operations block the whole table for other transactions.

Comment: H2 1.4.200 was released and it has `READ_UNCOMMITTED`, `READ_COMMITTED`, `REPEATABLE READ`, and `SNAPSHOT` isolation levels in the default engine.

Answer (score 0):

I added two connections, changed then isolation level, my question is why the second transaction not see the changes which is done by first transaction. First transaction not commit changes so if the transaction isolation level is TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED the second transaction should have see the changes from first transaction.

I know that:

H2 supports only three isolation levels; read uncommitted, read committed and serializable which can only be set at the connection level (not per transaction). The default is read committed.

```
public class StartUseCases {

    private static Connection connection;

    private static Connection connection2;

    public StartUseCases() {
        try {

            connection = ConnectionManager.getConnectionManager();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);

            connection2 = ConnectionManager.getConnectionManager();
            connection2.setAutoCommit(false);
            connection2.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);

            InitDatabaseManager.initStarterTable(connection);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        // init tables
        new StartUseCases();

        CRUD.getAllUsers(connection);
        CRUD.insertUsers(connection2);
        CRUD.getAllUsers(connection);
    }

}
```

Comment: here "answer" doesn't mean "response", it means "proposed solution", please edit this into in the question where people can find it easily.